# Scala: How to map values into lists based on a function

Tags: list, scala, sorting, csv, dictionary

I need to sort a list of towns/cities based on if they're in Ohio or not. The data is in a CSV file, so I don't really need to check if they are or not. I just need to sort them.

So here's what I have for data:

```
List(List("Jacksonville","Y"),List("BeverlyHills", "N"),List("NewYork","N"),List("Greensville", "Y"))
```

And I need to convert it into two lists where one list is where the function is true, and the other false. For instance, after I will have:

```
(List("Jacksonville","Greensville"),List("NewYork","BeveryHills");
```

The first list is where the function was true, while the second is where it was false.

This is what I have so far:

```
def isInOhio(place: String): Boolean = {
  place == "Y"
}
val sortedData = data.map({ case List(a, b) => (a, isMale(b)) })
```

As far as I know, the above function places the values into a map based on the results of the inner function. But it also brings the 'b' value into the map, which I don't need. I just want the 'a' values in the list.

Comment: Do you need to keep the non-Ohio values?

Comment: At a minimum, I suggest actually using the `Boolean` type rather than `String`, which is not limited to `"Y"` and `"N"` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `partition` method:

```
def isInOhio(csvLine: List[String]) = csvLine.last == "Y"      
data.partition(isInOhio)
```

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `groupBy` method. This will allow you to group the lists in two, based on the return value of the function.

```
data.groupBy({ case List(_, value) => isInOhio(value) })
.map({
    case (true, List(_, value)) => // Is in Ohio
    case (false, List(_, value)) => // Not in Ohio
}).sortBy(_._2.last)
```

This will leave you with a list containing a `Tuple` of the a Boolean and the original value: `(Boolean, List(a, b))`, where the `Boolean` value is the result of the `isInOhio` function:

```
List((true, List(a, b),
    (false, List(a, b)
    ...)
```

Now if you only want to keep one of the elements, just return only that like from the `map` function:

```
        case (true, List(_, value)) => value
```

And you will get:

```
List((true, b,
    (false, b
    ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the cities that exist in Ohio, you can do the following:

```
val cities = List("Jacksonville", "Greensville", "New York", "Beverly Hills")
val sortedOhioCities = cities.filter(isInOhio(_)).sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the inner lists tuples instead, then use the partition method

```
def isMale(str: String): Boolean = ???

List(("Jacksonville","Y"),("BeverlyHills", "N"),("NewYork","N"),("Greensville", "Y"))
.partition { 
  case (city, toggle) => isMale(toggle) 
} match {
  case (l1, l2) => (l1.map(_._1), l2.map(_._1))
}
```

This will produce `(List("Jacksonville","Greensville"),List("NewYork","BeveryHills"))`